# MVC Razor: De que forma puedo inicializar DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<Entidad>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

Les comento rapidamente: por la arquitectura del sistema hay una forma "facil" de llegar a la base de datos para hacer update y delete, la cual es a través de **DependencyResolver**. Copio codigo para que tengan una idea:

```
IEntityService<Persona> servicePersona = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IEntityService<Persona>>();
```

con esta forma puedo ir a la base y hacer consultas de la siguiente forma:

```
Persona resultPersona = new Persona();            
resultPersona = servicePersona.Queryable().ToList().Where(c=>c.CuilCuit==Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Esto funciona perfecto, el problema es cuando quiero hacer update/delete, dado que no realizo una asignacion, sino que hago una llamada directa a una clase no inicializada:

```
IAssistant<Persona> servicePersona2 = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAssistant<Persona>>();
```

Deberia poder borrar facilmente con el siguiente codigo:

```
servicePersona2.Service.Delete(servicePersona.Queryable().ToList().Where(c => c.CuilCuit == "1111111111").FirstOrDefault());
servicePersona2.UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

El problema es que me da el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguno tuvo oportunidad de hacer un update/delete de forma similar? Como resolvieron la inicializacion? Gracias!

Comment: vamos por partes, si recién andas iniciando con ASP.net MVC, te recomiendo preparar popcorn, conseguir unos refrescos y darle play a https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY son 4 horas 4 minutos y 4 segundos de entrenamiento con dicho framework, desde cero, explicando a detalle lo mejor que pude en aquel entonces :D

Comment: El tema es que no es un proyecto de 0. Tiene una cadena de herencias rigida que parte desde una sobrecarga del propio Datacontext y sobrecarga todos los metodos Delete() para borrar por identity de columna. Mi idea es aprovechar hasta donde pueda el codigo. En internet vi que puede ser un "bug" de una .dll. https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/810098/bug-an-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-error-occurs-when-you-try-to-access-data-by-using-ado-interop-on-an-asp-net-page

Comment: Tambien vi que se debe a que esa implementacion "DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<...." solo sirve para guardar informacion en una variable, para ejecutar hay que usar algo asi: "DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));" pero no lo he podido resolver.

Comment: Algo asi necesito, pero no creo que sea tan simple de implementar: http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Documentation/DependencyResolver

Answer (score 0):

Al final opte por instalar el paquete Nuget "Entity Framework" y levantar la base y los modelos desde 0, con eso se resolvieron todos mis problemas a la hora de usar conectores contra la base, de hecho, entity framework te ofrece una comunicacion rapida sin necesidad de tanto codigo. Les dejo el link por las dudas si alguien quiere usarlo:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/695850/Complete-CRUD-Operations-in-MVC